# What version of iText does razor pdf use?

Tags: pdf, razorpdf

iText version 5 required license and cannot be used in closed applications, version previous do not require. does any one know which itext version does nuget package razor pdf uses?

Answer (score 1):

[It's 4.1.2](https://github.com/RazorAnt/RazorPDF). But you can find its latest LGPL copy here: https://github.com/itextsharper/iTextSharp-4.1.6

Answer (score 0):

You can install it from Nuget.

```
PM> install-package itextsharp -Version 4.1.2
```